# Getting more detail from the Spring cloud Discovery Client

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I note that with the various refactoring of common elements into spring cloud commons, the information that you get from auto wiring DiscoveryClient is rather sparse.

Lets say that I want to get more information for the incoming service data that the service gets when it registers with Eureka.  Much of what i want is in the Application object.

I know that I could get this detail form the EurekaClient.  How can I get access to the EurekaClient object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you mean `InstanceInfo` objects, since `Application` basically just holds a list on `InstanceInfo`'s. The `ServiceInstance` returned from the Spring Cloud `DiscoveryClient.getInstances(serviceId)` backed by an `InstanceInfo`. My guess is it would be easiest for you to autowire `EurekaClient` (or `com.netflix.*.DiscoveryClient` if your using an older version) and go from there. We have to be sparse as we support more than just eureka (consul, zookeeper).

Comment: yes, InstanceInfo.  After I wrote this I went through the code base and found the @EurekaClient annotation and am trying a quick test using the EurekaClient to get instances for what I want.  I needed to get more information including the actual service metadata for each registration.